# New list longest consecutive streak of values

Tags: python, list

I want program that outputs a list consisting of the longest streak of consecutive occurrences of the same value in L in PYTHON.

In case multiple values have the equal number of streak, smallest value is chosen.

Input:

```
L=[2,4,3,3,3,5,6,7,7,7]
```

Output:

```
R=[3,3,3]
```

Code

```
R = L
i=0
for i in range(len(L)-1):
    if L[i]==L[i+1]:
    R=[L[i],L[i+1]]
    i=i+1
    else:
    R=[]
print('\nThe longest streak of the same value is:')
print('  ', R)
```

Comment: What does Xcode have to do with this?

Comment: Sorry @ShawnicHedgehog

Comment: What have you tried? Post that, and what didn't work, and we'll help.

Comment: Could you provide code that you have tried? This isn't a forum for us to do homework for you.

Comment: @ShawnicHedgehog I have pasted code

Comment: @ShadowRanger Hi I have added the code. please help

Comment: @SwarnavaMukhopadhyay: The indentation there is completely wrong, so it's impossible to tell what the code is doing. Please fix the indentation.

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> longest = max((list(g) for _, g in groupby(L)), key=len)
>>> longest
[3, 3, 3]
```

There are actually two groups of 3, so I presume you want the first of such groups.

`groupby` returns two things. The grouped element and the group, we only care about the later. So we make a list of just the grouper elements, use `list` to convert them from grouper objects, which have no `len` function.

Now we can use `max` to determine the largest element, returning the first such element in the event of a tie. We need to use a `key` function as using `max` on lists themselves has no meaning. So pass `len` as the `key` function used to determine `max`ness.

I notice you ask that the item with the lowest value is selected, rather than the first in the list. This complicates matter a little. Although your code makes no effort to account for it, heres a solution.

Instead now you have to create a list just of the elements that have the longest length `[[3,3,3], [7,7,7]]` and select the value with the lower value.

Trying to do this in a one liner might be a bit much.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
L=[2,4,3,3,3,5,6,7,7,7]

# list of groupers, converted to list
groups = [list(g) for _, g in groupby(L)]

# read longest value across all groups
longest = max(map(len, groups))

# filter any smaller groups from the list
# and find the entry with the lowest (min) number in it
result = min(filter(lambda g: len(g) == longest, groups), key=itemgetter(0))

print(result)
```

Try switching the final `min` call for a `max` and see that a different entry is chosen.

Or more simply, as pointed out by @ShadowRanger in comments, you can return a tuple of length and negated value from the key function to favour lower values in the event of a tie in length. To favour larger values, remove the negation.

```
longest = max((list(g) for _, g in groupby(L)), key=lambda g: (len(g), -g[0]))
```

Comment: The "push it all to C" version to eliminate byte code execution per item to speed it up when given large inputs: `max(map(list, map(operator.itemgetter(1), itertools.groupby(it))), key=len)`

Comment: FYI, for the numeric case, making it return the smallest value of ties for max length is still easy. Just change the `key` to `lambda x: (len(x), -x[0])`. Loses the "wholly C" aspect of my all C version, but what can you do?

Answer (score 0):

Below python code will do the same. @Paul's version is more Pythonic

```
lst = [2,4,3,3,3,5,6,7,7,7, 7]
n = len(lst)

# Store overall max consecutive length
max_len = 1
num = lst[0]

#  Store current consecutive length
cur_len = 1
cur_num = lst[0]

for i in range(1, n):
   if lst[i] == cur_num:
     cur_len += 1
   elif cur_len > max_len:
     max_len = cur_len
     num = cur_num   
     cur_num = lst[i]
     cur_len = 1
   else:
     cur_num = lst[i]


if cur_len > max_len:
    num = lst[-1]
    max_len = cur_len


print [num]*max_len
```